# Cannot upgrade Firebase apps from legacy to new console

Tags: firebase

I'm unable to upgrade a specific existing Firebase app to the new Firebase 3 console. I'm not sure why because I was able to do it before without issue.So far I've:

Logged in to Legacy console

Clicked on the `upgrade` option for the app I want to transfer over

The Firebase 3 console opens but app is not there

I looked around for directions on how to proceed but have only found instructions to look below the Firebase 3 project list section to see the list of my old projects at `Firebase.com` and import them from there. The problem is I don't see anything but this error message.

[image]

I have clicked the `linked your account` but all that does is bring me back to the legacy console with no further instruction or confirmation that the account has been linked. When I go back to the Firebase 3 console there is still nothing there.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I recommend that you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services/) so that someone can look into it. I doubt developers here on Stack Overflow can help with this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and link!